# Android Migration To Android studio 3.0 Manifest Errors

Tags: android-studio-3.0

After Automatic actualization To Android 3.0 I keep Getting Manifest Error Althought Nothing was Changed by me In It.
I had Tried to
1) Reinstall Android Studio couple time
2) Clean Cache
3) Download SDK One more Time
4)I was Searching For inconsistience in build gradle.
Nothink Helped, One of Many problems in Manifest is That
Te fatal Problem is Error:(82) error: unknown element  found.

MY MANIFEST

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.lenovo.licz4"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="26" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS"
        android:maxSdkVersion="22" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_STATS" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS"
        android:maxSdkVersion="22" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.VERSION"
        android:value="26.0.0-alpha1" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.lenovo.licz4.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.lenovo.licz4.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" >
        <service
            android:name="com.example.lenovo.licz4.SyncService"
            android:exported="true"
            android:process=":com.example.lenovo.licz4.sync" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter"
                android:resource="@xml/syncadapter" />
        </service>
        <service android:name="com.example.lenovo.licz4.AuthenticatorService" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator"
                android:resource="@xml/authenticator" />
        </service>

        <provider
            android:name="com.example.lenovo.licz4.StubProvider"
            android:authorities="com.example.lenovo.licz4"
            android:exported="false"
            android:syncable="true" />

        <activity android:name="com.example.lenovo.licz4.Activities.CopyDbActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <account-authenticator
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:accountType="http://example.com/"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:smallIcon="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" >
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementInstallReferrerReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" />

        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="com.example.lenovo.licz4" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <!--

        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver"
            android:exported="false" />

        <service
            android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter android:priority="-500" >
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <provider
            android:name="com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider"
            android:authorities="com.example.lenovo.licz4.firebaseinitprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:initOrder="100" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

MY BUILD GRADLE

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
 classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}


apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.lenovo.licz4"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })




    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:0.6.0'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}



apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 2):

I too had this problem and almost tried what you have tried.
My problem was solved by adding

```
android.enableAapt2=false
```

on `grable.properties` of project.
I hope this will help you too.

Comment: Thank You very much ! It helped!

Comment: Great. If it helped you would you mind marking my answer as the correct one?

Comment: this is not the correct answer. Check:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46976562/my-android-manifest-is-full-of-errors-after-updating-to-android-3-0-0