# My Android manifest is full of errors after updating to Android 3.0.0

Tags: java, android

I'm badly stuck after updating to Android 3.0.0 and gradle update to 4.1. My app is not building and the manifest contains a lot of errors. I tried cleaning the project under `Build`, invalidate caches/restart under `Files`, without success.

The errors I recieve are as following:

> Error:(52) error: unknown element  found.
>   Error:(52) unknown element  found.
>   Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:  java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception:   AAPT2 error: check logs for details
>   Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
>   Error:com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
>   Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
>   Failed to execute aapt

All errors are in `debug\AndroidManifest`. When I delete or comment the marked activities, they're getting added back on gradle build,

I'm also getting an 'URI not registrered error too with `android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`'

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="sample.app"
    android:installLocation="auto"
    android:versionCode="48"
    android:versionName="4.8" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="19"
        android:targetSdkVersion="25" />
    //Hardware Constraints for Application
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />

    <!-- <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network" /> -->

    //Required App Permissions
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT" />

    <uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.VERSION"
        android:value="25.3.1" />

    <activity android:name="com.box.androidsdk.content.auth.OAuthActivity" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer"
        android:required="true" /> <!-- Permissions required for GCM -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <permission
        android:name="sample.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="sample.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <!--
  <uses-feature
          android:name="android.hardware.camera2.full"
          android:required="true" />
    -->
    <!--
   <uses-feature
           android:name="android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer"
           android:required="true" />
    -->
    <application
        android:name="sample.app.dailymotion.volleyapp.AppController"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <!--
             <meta-data
             android:name="com.google.android.gms.vision.DEPENDENCIES"
             android:value="barcode"/>
        -->
        <activity android:name="sample.app.SplashScreen" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="sample.app.ClrInfo"
            android:exported="false"
            android:theme="@style/MyDialogTheme" />

</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: check https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/10/android-studio-30.html

Comment: post your `mainfest.xml`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Android docs mentioned about the migration guide here : https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html

> **Element hierarchies in the Android manifest**
>
> In previous versions of AAPT, elements nested in incorrect nodes in
>   the Android manifest are either ignored or result in a warning. For
>   example, consider the following sample:
>
> ```
> <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>    package="com.example.myname.myapplication">
>    <application
>        ...
>        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
>            <intent-filter>
>                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
>                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
>            </intent-filter>
>            <action android:name="android.intent.action.CUSTOM" />
>        </activity>
>    </application>
> </manifest>
> ```

Note that you must check your Manifest if you really comply to the specific nesting rule they provided otherwise your app wont compile.

> **Manifest file structure**
>
> The code snippet below shows the general structure of the manifest
>   file and every element that it can contain. Each element, along with
>   all of its attributes, is fully documented in a separate file.
>
> ```
> <manifest>
>
>     <uses-permission />
>     <permission />
>     <permission-tree />
>     <permission-group />
>     <instrumentation />
>     <uses-sdk />
>     <uses-configuration />  
>     <uses-feature />  
>     <supports-screens />  
>     <compatible-screens />  
>     <supports-gl-texture />  
>
>     <application>
>
>         <activity>
>             <intent-filter>
>                 <action />
>                 <category />
>                 <data />
>             </intent-filter>
>             <meta-data />
>         </activity>
>
>         <activity-alias>
>             <intent-filter> . . . </intent-filter>
>             <meta-data />
>         </activity-alias>
>
>         <service>
>             <intent-filter> . . . </intent-filter>
>             <meta-data/>
>         </service>
>
>         <receiver>
>             <intent-filter> . . . </intent-filter>
>             <meta-data />
>         </receiver>
>
>         <provider>
>             <grant-uri-permission />
>             <meta-data />
>             <path-permission />
>         </provider>
>
>         <uses-library />
>
>     </application>
>
> </manifest>
> ```

In your case you must transfer your

`<activity android:name="com.box.androidsdk.content.auth.OAuthActivity" />`

inside in `<application>` so that it will compile.

**Disabling AAPT2 is just a workaround but not a real answer**.

Comment: You saved my life..Great. thanks a lot.

Comment: @Panache you are welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

No need to disable AAPT2. :) In line 56 of your AndroidManifest.xml you define an activity:

```
<activity android:name="com.box.androidsdk.content.auth.OAuthActivity" />
```

The 'activity' tag can only be nested under the 'application' element. For more info please look at the [Android Manifest structure documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html#filestruct).